# Is there any way to update/select data in one column when the value of another column appears in MSSQL 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i know the question itself is kinda confusing and I am not sure how to phrase it therefore I would like to give some examples to better explain my problem.

First I would be extracting the data for verification from the application database. Therefore the extracted data would be in the table format(s) as below

```
VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 1 NO = OM1, VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO = OM2, VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO = OM3, VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO = OM4, BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO = OG1, BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO = OG2, BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO = OG3, BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO = OG4
```

First Scenario:

```
GUID    Name                                Value  TimeStamp
----    --------------------------------    -----  ---------
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO     10      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO     20      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO     30      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO     40      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 1 NO          50      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO          60      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO     70      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO     80      11:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO     90      12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO     100     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO     110     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO     120     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 1 NO          130     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO          140     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO     150     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO     160     12:00
```

Expected Outcome for first scenario:

```
GUID    Name                               Value  TimeStamp
----   ---------------------------------   -----  ---------
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO    10      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO    20      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO    30      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO    40      11:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO    90      12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO    100     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO    110     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO    120     12:00
```

2nd Scenario

```
GUID    Name                                Value  TimeStamp
----    --------------------------------    -----  ---------
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO     10      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO     20      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 1 NO          50      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO          60      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO     70      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO     80      11:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO     90      12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO     100     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO     110     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO     120     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 1 NO          130     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO          140     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO     150     12:00
2222    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO     160     12:00
```

Expected Outcome for 2nd Scenario:

```
GUID    Name                               Value  TimeStamp
----   ---------------------------------   -----  ---------
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO    10      11:00
1111    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO    20      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO    70      11:00
1111    VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO    80      11:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO    90      12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO    100     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO    110     12:00
2222    BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO    120     12:00
```

From the tables, the BOAR(s) values would always be shown after query, if there are not BOAR values, it will then take the VAB(s) values to replace the BOAR(s) values.If there is no BOAR(s) or VAB(s) values, the records would not be shown.Any assistance provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `row_number`. This solution assumes that the `X` is always three positions from the last character.

```
select guid, name, value, timestamp
from (
   select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by guid, substring(name, len(name)-3,1) order by name) rn
   from data
) t
where rn = 1
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98bf38dc2e9a1597b659078e34587ce9)

Comment: i have shorten the naming convention for the column in `NAME` thus its not possible to use the substring  as partitioning

Comment: VAB MMO BeerfestCircle  1 NO = OM1,                                                                                              
VAB MMO BeerfestCircle 2 NO = OM2,
VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 1 NO = OM3,
VAB MMO BeerfestOutdazzling 2 NO = OM4,
BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 1 NO = OG1,
BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Out 2 NO = OG2,
BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 1 NO = OG3,
BOAR VAP EG SAM Blaster Cir 2 NO = OG4,

Comment: You should update your question accordingly. It seems that the important number is always at the end of the value right?

Comment: Ok, I have changed the answer according to your updates